# Update or append to a subcollection in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection containing a subcollection. In one request, I would like to update a record in the subcollection or append to it if a match doesn't exist. For a bonus point I would also like this update to be a merge rather than an overwrite.

A crude example:

```
// Schema
{
    subColl: [
        {
            name: String,
            value: Number,
            other: Number,
        },
    ];
}

// Existing record
{
    _id : 123,
    subColl: [
        {name: 'John',
        value: 10,
        other: 20}
    ]
}

// example
const update = { _id: 123, name: 'John', other: 1000 };
const { _id, name, other } = update;
const doc = await Schema.findById(_id);
const idx = doc.subColl.findIndex(({ name: nameInDoc }) => nameInDoc === name);
if (idx >= 0) {
    doc.subColl[idx] = { ...doc.subColl[idx], other };
} else {
    doc.subColl.push({ name, other });
}
doc.save();
```

Currently I can achieve this result by pulling the record, and doing the update/append manually but I am assuming that achieving it with a pure mongo query would be much faster.

I have tried:

```
Schema.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: 123, 'subColl.name': 'John' },
    { $set: { 'subColl.$': [{ name: 'John', other: 1000 }] } }
)
```

but this won't handle the append behaviour and also doesn't merge the object with the existing record, rather it overwrites it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure is there any straight way to do this in single query,

#### [Update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB v4.2,

- `$cond` to check name is in `subColl` array,
- true condition, need to merge with existing object, `$map` to iterate loop, check condition if matches condition then merge new data object with current object using `$mergeObjects`
- false condition, need to concat arrays, current `subColl` array and new object using `$concatArrays`

```
const _id = 123;
const update = { name: 'John', other: 1000 };

Schema.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: _id },
  [{
    $set: {
      subColl: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [update.name, "$subColl.name"] },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$subColl",
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this.name", update.name] },
                  { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", update] },
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          { $concatArrays: ["$subColl", [update]] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LHAizBvczgD)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works as expected in your playground but having transformed the names to those actually in use in my app, the only behaviour I am getting is the array being set to length 1, with an empty object as the only element. I had to remove the outer square braces from outside the $set object to avoid an error so wonder if this could be causing it? (mongoose v5.11.11) Equally, can you suggest how one might debug such nested aggregation operations individually? I have no experience with queries this complex!

Comment: the braces [] is required in aggregation pipeline, you are getting error because of your mongodb version is below 4.2, i have mentioned that in answer this feature is starting from mongodb 4.2, can you confirm your mongodb installed version? *can you suggest how one might debug* => you can debug in playground, and learn about operators that is starts `$` from [aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) i would suggest learn some basic queries and aggregation pipeline from mongodb docs if you have no experience.

Comment: Your requirement is complex, i don't think any other way to do this in simple query. or you can do 2 queries, first find and then update.

Comment: Ah apologies, you're right. Mongo is only v3.0.15. I'll upgrade it and see if that resolves.

Comment: Answer now accepted, I can confirm it does work. Sadly not as much faster than the crude method as I'd hoped!